# Проблема с редактированием XML Android

Tags: java, android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/question_from_secodActiv"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/question"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:text="@string/chosen_recomendation"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="205dp"
        android:text="111111"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#c266ff"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
        android:text="2222222"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#ad33ff"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="335dp"
        android:text="333333"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#9900ff"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
        android:text="4444444"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#7a00cc"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="465dp"
        android:text="555555"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#5c0099"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Необходима подсказка или помощь с одним активити. В одном активити 2 Text View и 5 Button
суть в чем, при смене ориентации, не помещаются все элементы, пытался сделать через Recycler ничего не получилось. Как сделать, чтоб независимо от масштабов смартфона все элементы могли помещаться или хотя бы прокручиваться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы сидите внутри `RelativeLayout`, то попытки выравнивания с помощью `layout_marginTop` и `XXXdp` до добра не доведут.

Если я правильно понимаю ваш лейаут есть 2 `TextView`, под которыми вы пытаетесь поместить несколько `Button`. Способов решения масса, ну например:

Внутри `RelativeLayout` помещаем оба `LinearLayout` с флагом `orientation=vertical`, первый прижимаем к верхней части `RelativeLayout` атрибутом `layout_alignParentTop="true"`, второй помещаем под ним с атрибутом `layout_below="@+id/firstLayout"`

В первый пихаем по очереди `TextView` с атрибутами `android:layout_width="match_parent"` и
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, во второй пихаем `Button` с аналогичными атрибутами